# OctoberCms backend file upload button does not react

Tags: octobercms

Created a plugin using builder and creating form to manage categories database records. Also I want to upload image for category. Created required fields including file upload, however when i click on file upload button - nothing happens, no reaction at all. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you added in your model a `$attachOne` or `$attachMany` attribute.

For example:

```
public $attachOne = [
    'my_file' => 'System\Models\File',
];
```

Then in your `fields.yaml` file make sure to write a code like this:

```
my_file:
    type: fileupload
    label: My File
```

If you did all of these steps correctly try to update OctoberCMS to the latest version.

If the problem continues try to open the console and click on the upload button and see is there a problem displayed in the console after clicking or not.

And the last thing is to make sure from your browser. Try another browser.

Comment: Ok i have figured out. When creating form i have added advanced options to trigger event and that's when it messed up the button. I have removed triggers and now button works fine.